# foreach loop question

Tags: c#, foreach

Is there any other shorter/more efficient way to check and see if it is the last item in my ListBox? The main goal here is basically to add the selected items to a label, and add a comma after every one but the last one. Any suggestions?

```
        int sc = 0;
        List<string> interestitems = new List<string>();

        foreach (ListItem siitem in ListBox1.Items)
        {
            if (siitem.Selected == true)
            {
               interestitems.Add(siitem.Value.ToString());
            }
        }

        foreach (string inteitem in interestitems)
        {
            Label1.Text += inteitem;
            sc++;
            if (sc < interestitems.Count)
            {
                Label1.Text += ",";
            }
        }
```

Comment: Please don't use names like `Label1` or `ListBox1`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Instead of your second loop just use:

```
Label1.Text = string.Join("," , interestitems);
```

---

**P.S.**

if you're using .net 3.5, you need to pass an array of strings to `string.Join()`, then :

```
Label1.Text = string.Join("," , interestitems.ToArray());
```

---

**EDIT:**

If you want to completely avoid looping just do:

```
var selItems = ListBox1.Items.Cast<ListItem>()
                       .Where(item => item.Selected)
                       .Select(item => item.ToString());

Label1.Text = string.Join("," , selItems);
```

Comment: +1 that is a great idea.  Normally I just use a `StringBuilder` and then remove the last instance of ','.

Comment: Maybe you need `string.Join(",",interestitems.ToArray())`

Comment: I wish I could mark this as the answer. That oft-repeated comma loop drives me mad.

Comment: @ja72: not in .net 4, added a side note though ;)

Comment: @Ritch - I agree. I think most people when they see `string.Join()` they confuse it with `string.Concat()` and don't investigate further on what it does. Thanks Microsoft for included this in .NET from the beginning, as I have used it 1,000 times by now.

Answer (score 2):

How about LINQ:

```
Label1.Text = string.Join(
    ",", 
    ListBox1.Items
            .OfType<ListItem>()
            .Where(item => item.Selected)
            .Select(x => x.Value.ToString())
            .ToArray()
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace all of your code with some LINQ:

```
Label1.Text = String.Join(", ",
              ListBox1.Items.Cast<ListItem>()
                            .Where(i => i.Selected)
                            .Select(i => i.Value.ToString())
              );
```

In .Net 3.5, you'll need to add `.ToArray()`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can do this:

```
interestitems.IndexOf(inteitem);
```

Altought it worked me with other item types, may give you an idea. I haven't checked if it works with strings.

The you just have to eliminate the last one, with the index check if it's the last ones with interestitems.Count

Answer (score 0):

Why not just build up the string as you iterate during the first loop

```
var builder = new StringBuilder();
var first = true;
foreach (var item in ListBox1.Items) {
  if (item.Selected) {
    if (!first) {
      builder.Append(", ");
    }
    first = false;
    builder.Append(item.Value.ToString());
  }
}

Label1.Text = builder.ToString();
```